# Log Likelihood using R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a probability density function (PDF)

```
(1-cos(x-theta))/(2*pi)
```

theta is the unknown parameter. How do I write a log likelihood function for this PDF? I am confused; the `x` will come from my data, but how do I handle the `theta` in the equation.
Thanks

Comment: see http://www.crossvalidated.com for statistical questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you wrote is a likelihood function of `theta` given the known `x`:

```
ll(theta|x) = log((1-cos(x-theta))/(2*pi))
```

if you have many iid observations from this distribution, x1,x2,...xn just take the sum of the above:

```
ll(theta|x1,x2,...) = Sum[log((1-cos(xi-theta))/(2*pi))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an optimisation or maximisation function in R to compute the value of theta that maximises the log-likelihood. See help(nlmin) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

If f(x_i) = (1-cos(x_i-theta))/(2*pi) for observation i, then likelihood function L(Theta)=product(f(x_i)) and logL(theta)=sum(f(x_i)), of course assuming that x_i are independent.

Answer (score -4):

I think log-likelihood only works for normal-distributions. The special property of the log-function is, that it cancels out the exp-function, but here's no exp-function.

Btw., your PDF is periodic and theta just manipulates the phase of that function. Where does this PDF come from? What should it describe?

Comment: it is one function from a set. I am testing different algorithms to get Maximum log likelihood. (I am not a statistician)

Comment: Rule of thumb: In dubio pro normal-distribution. ;)

Comment: No, log-likelihood works for any distributions. The likelihood is the product of a number of probabilities, so the log-likelihood is the sum of the probabilities - makes the calculations easier, especially when multiplying lots of near-zero or near-one probabilities.

Comment: This is patently not true, Dominik. People are maximising LLs for all sorts of probability distributions every second of the day.

Comment: But I guess you can't maximize the log-likelihood function of the above PDF analytically as you can with a normal-distribution. You'll have to apply some kind of gradient descent method, right? Yes, I admit, calculation of the derivative is much simpler if you have a sum instead of a product. I'm sorry, I did a mistake.